# I accidentally typed offset from the homerow

Tags: cipher

And so I told my co-worker, "don't try to translate that, it's not worth the time." He proceeded to try, but could not solve it.
Here you go.

```
fon'y sdk rudyiond.
```

There's a few posisbilities he didnt take into account.

Comment: Hi Cody, welcome to puzzlingSE. It's great to see a new face here. Don't be shy posting questons (or answers), but please don't take down-votes personally (I actually did downvote the puzzle - just becaues I think it isn't a very good one.) To quite some extend, this site is meant to "teach" puzzle-building, so getting criticised is part of the game :c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the desired answer is

> **don't ask questions**

based on

> your left hand being shifted to the right by one key while typing.

The only problem is that

> you will actually get **don't ask eustions** using this method.  A "proper" puzzle would use the phrase "fon'y sdk ***w***​u​***r***​dyiond" instead.

Comment: Wouldn't it be "w​urdyiond" instead?

Comment: Hmmm, my last line was meant to be part of the puzzle :), I don't know if that makes it a proper puzzle in your mind or not :D